# Binary search through a list

Tags: python, binary-search

I have this code

```
def readCountries(self):
    countryList = []
    with open('countries.txt', 'r') as countryText:
        for line in open('countries.txt', 'r'):
            countries = countryText.read()
            countryList.append(line.strip().split())
        return countryList
```

Τhis code outputs `countries.txt` like this:

> [["Afghanistan",647500.0,25500100],["Albania",28748.0,2821977],...,["Zimbabwe",390580.0,12973808]]

Ιt goes by `[name, area, population]`. What I am trying to do is write a function that calls the answer from the code above to get the list of countries and do a binary search and print a country information if it is found. Example :

```
printCountry("Canada")

  Canada, Area: 9976140.0,  Population: 35295770

 printCountry("Winterfell")

  I'm sorry, could not find Winterfell in the country list.
```

I do not know how to do this part, any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you just want to find the country but don't want to implement a binary search yourself, python provides a bisect library for doing binary searches.

Comment: Have you considered usingva dictionary instead of a list? This seems to be a typical scenario where you should use them.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps:

```
def binary_search(clist, cname):
    low = 0
    high = len(clist)
    while low<=high: 
        mid = int((low+high)/2)
        print(mid, low, high)
        if clist[mid][0]== cname:
            return clist[mid]
        elif clist[mid][0] > cname:
            high = mid-1
        else:
            low = mid+1

def printCountry(self,country_name):
    country = binary_search(self.countryList, country_name)
    if country:
        print("{0}, Area:{1}, Population:{2}".format(country[0],    country[1], country[2]))
    else:
        print("I'm sorry, could not find {0} in the country list.".format(country_name))
```